# Unknown table from field list?

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert

I tried to write a trigger procedure for my database.

```
    DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER studenteGioca BEFORE INSERT ON Gioca
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
            if(new.anno - EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Studente.anno_iscrizione)<2)
        then SIGNAL SQLSTATE '71261'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT='Lo studente non puo giocare nella squadra al primo anno di scuola';
        end if;
    END;
    //
DELIMITER ;
```

The tables involved are **Gioca** and **Studente**. In gioca I have an int called *anno*, which represents a year. in Studente I have a date called *anno_iscrizione*.
What I want to do is a trigger that doesn't permit an insert in Gioca if the difference between anno and the year of anno_iscrizione is less than two.
But when I insert something in the table Gioca, it gives me the error "Unknown table 'Studente' in field list"

How should I correct the trigger?

Comment: You cannot have a FROM without a SELECT and you need a FROM <tablename>. I suspect you also need to test for a match on student.

Comment: Please add your table definitions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the appropriate studente and if  Studente.anno_iscrizione is a date datatype then YEAR function would be ok. I have assumed the name of the student id column in both tables

```
if new.anno - (select YEAR(Studente.anno_iscrizione) from studente where studente.student_id = new.student_id) <2
```

Comment: Now it doesn't give me the error anymore, but I can insert values that shouldn't be accepted

Comment: Please add sample data and expected outcome as text.